# Importing users with Design Collaboration service access [autodesk-bim360]

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Looking at the request body structure for importing users into a project https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/ , it seems like we can only specify  the access level for the following two services: project_administration & document_management. How can I assign someone user level access to "design_collaboration" when importing? When attempting to do so I get: `"errors":[{"message":"Invalid services [\"design_collaboration\"]","code":2000}]`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is currently a limitation, only project_administration & document_management are supported as documented, this is a frequently asked request, and it's still under development.

Comment: Oh, I searched for "design_collaboration" and had no results. Now that I search for "design collaboration" I see some results from 2018 . Thank you for responding